# Gitkraken missing menubar(toolbar)

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, git

I have been using gitkraken for quite a while right now.However I noticed that after v2.5 the top menu bar which includes minimize close button is missing.As a result I cannot minimize or close gitkraken.If I want to switch to another application I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> .I am using ubuntu 17.04 budgie remix.

Here is a photo of how it looks like:

[image: Gitkraken missing bar]

Any ideas?

Comment: The top menu bar may be hidden under the top panel. Try ALT-spacebar and choose unmaximize from the menu, or ALT-click_and_hold in the window and drag the window down to find the top menu, and then you can resize.

Comment: i tried your first solution.It doesn't work

Comment: What about the 2nd solution?

Comment: I can't drag the window cause there is nothing to drag.While this window is active I can't do anything

Comment: Test either of my suggestions on a standard size Nautilus file manager window to make sure that you're doing it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after contacting gitkraken support the solution has been found.
It seems that GitKraken was in full screen mode

So to exit full screen mode I had to press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd>